# Export tables from multiple databases and import into a single database

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I would like to export specific data from three table with the same name from multiple databases and import them into a single database `SUPPORT_DATABASE`, the tables are `XXX_users`, `XXX_usergroups`, `XXX-user_usergroup_map`.

the user `id` is the primary key in all tables.

Here are the scripts i have so far

MySQL-Export.php

```
<?php
//ENTER THE RELEVANT INFO BELOW
$mysqlDatabaseName ='db1';
$mysqlUserName ='db1owner';
$mysqlPassword ='Password';
$mysqlHostName ='db1.mywebhost.net';
$mysqlExportPath ='db1backup.sql';

//DONT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
//Export the database and output the status to the page
$command='mysqldump --opt -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p'    .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'
SELECT id, name, username, password, email FROM `xxx_users` WHERE `id` in (SELECT `user_id` FROM `xxx_user_usergroup_map` WHERE `group_id` = (SELECT `id`     FROM `xxx_usergroups` WHERE `title` = 'Administrator'));
SELECT id, name, username, password, email FROM `xxx_users` WHERE `id` in (SELECT `user_id` FROM `xxx_user_usergroup_map` WHERE `group_id` = (SELECT `id` FROM `xxx_usergroups` WHERE `title` = 'Engineer'));
> ~/' .$mysqlExportPath;
exec($command,$output=array(),$worked);
switch($worked){
case 0:
echo 'Database <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b> successfully exported to <b>~/' .$mysqlExportPath .'</b>';
break;
case 1:
echo 'There was a warning during the export of <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b> to <b>~/' .$mysqlExportPath .'</b>';
break;
case 2:
echo 'There was an error during export. Please check your values:<br/><br/><table><tr><td>MySQL Database Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL User Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlUserName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Password:</td><td><b>NOTSHOWN </b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Host Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlHostName .'</b></td></tr></table>';
break;
}
?>
```

MySQL-Import.php

```
$mysqlDatabaseName ='db2';
$mysqlUserName ='db2owner';
$mysqlPassword ='Password';
$mysqlHostName ='db2.mywebhost.net';
$mysqlImportFilename ='db1backup.sql';

//DONT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
//Export the database and output the status to the page
$command='mysql -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' < ' .$mysqlImportFilename;
exec($command,$output=array(),$worked);
switch($worked){
case 0:
echo 'Import file <b>' .$mysqlImportFilename .'</b> successfully imported to    database <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b>';
break;
case 1:
echo 'There was an error during import. Please make sure the import file is saved in the same folder as this script and check your values:<br/><br/><table><tr><td>MySQL Database Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL User Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlUserName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Password:</td><td><b>NOTSHOWN</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Host Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlHostName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Import Filename:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlImportFilename .'</b></td></tr></table>';
break;
}
?>
```

Table structures

```
XXX_user
user_id, name, username, email, password
300, john smtih, jsmith, jsmith@test.com, password123@

XXX_usergroups
group_id, type
8, administrator

XXX_user_group_map
user_id, group_id
300, 8
```

What I thought I can do, is export the data from three databases using `MySQL-Export.php` and store the databases on the server, then import the databases using `MySQL-import.php`, from all three databases into an auxiliary database, once the data is here `MODIFY` the user `group_id` in `XXX-user_usergroup_map` to match the usergroups in the `SUPPORT_DATABASE`

at this point I am a little stuck, as importing users from multiple databases, the user may share the same `user_id`, so i am unsure what to do, where and how can i change the `user_id`.

It doesnt matter what the `user_id` is once it is on `SUPPORT_DATABASE`

can any body suggest some thing please.

Comment: Is XXX_usergroups the same across all three databases?

Comment: no, the `group_id` in `XXX_usergroup` will be different accross all three databases, however, once i import the data, i have a SQL script that will change them, i just dont know what to do with the `user_id`

Comment: Then just remove the user_id and let the SUPPORT_DATABASE auto increment the user_id for you

Comment: hi, thank you, i didnt think it would do that, how would it work if i ran the script daily, how would it override, would it be affected?

Comment: If the user email is unique, set email column as unique in the database then it will not be duplicate

Comment: i have amended my question to display the table structure, to explain the issue a little clearer, as the issue still resides within `XXX_user_group_map`

Comment: thie issue is, if i change the `user_id` in `XXX_user`, it will affect the `user_id` in XXX_user_gorup_map aswell

Answer (score 0):

Here one way to do it, step by step

1. Dump out each database by using this query

`SELECT u.name, u.username, u.email, u.password, g2.type FROM "XXX_user" u, "XXX_user_group_map" g, "XXX_usergroups" g2 WHERE g.user_id = u.user_id AND g.group_id = g2.group_id`

In this query, you'll get user group type as a string where you can use to match with your `SUPPORT_DATABASE` group id

2. Now write a script to import the sql into `SUPPORT_DATABASE`, set `SUPPORT_DATABASE` to have AUTO INCREMENT on user_id and unique on email.